# Computing and correcting for clock drift in an instrument

Tags: python, math, scipy, sympy

I'm attempting to implement the solution given to this question I recently posed over on Math SE. I'll recreate the relevant details here.

I have a system consisting of equations of the form:

[image]

Here, `c`, `a_ir`, and the vectors `p_r` are knowns. The vectors `x0` and `v`, as well as the `ti`'s are unknown. Further, `T` and `R` are known, but will vary (i.e. cannot be hard-coded).

I'm most familiar with the symbolic manipulation and solution of such systems, as well as the `SymPy` package, so I began there. Unfortunately, as it turns out, perhaps not surprisingly `SymPy`'s solvers aren't well-suited for such a problem. As the knowns in question will come from real-world experimental data, a solution(s) may only be obtained numerically, and `SymPy` offers only one numerical solver, `nsolve()`, which chocked up quickly.

I'd like to translate what I've done in `SymPy` to something compatible with `SciPy`, which offers far more flexibility and a host of linear and nonlinear solvers. Unfortunately, I'm not terribly familiar with `SciPy`, and it isn't clear to me how the very symbolic expressions I have in `SymPy` can be translated to `SciPy`.

---

Here's what I have thus far (admittedly, its a fairly crude first-draft):

```
T = 10; R = 3

x,y,z, vx,vy,vz = sp.symbols('x,y,z, vx,vy,vz', real=True)
collection = sp.symbols(" ".join(f"t{x}" for x in range(T)), real=True)
 
@dataclass
class Vertexer:
 
    receivers: list
 
    def find(self, data):
        eqs = []
 
        for r in range(R):
            for i in range(T):
                eqs.append(sp.Eq(c**2 * (data[r][i] - collection[i])**2, (vx**2 + vy**2 + vz**2) * (collection[i] - collection[0])**2 + 2 * (collection[i] - collection[0]) * (vx * (x - self.receivers[r][0]) + vy * (y - self.receivers[r][1]) + vz * (z - self.receivers[r][2])) + ((x - self.receivers[r][0])**2 + (y - self.receivers[r][1])**2 + (z - self.receivers[r][2])**2)))
                print(sp.nsolve(eqs, (x,y,z,vx,vy,vz) + collection))
```

Here, `data` is a `list` containing `R` lists of size `T`, which in turn contain the `air`'S. Eventually, `T` and `R` would be determined by the size of this matrix, not hard coded as done here. `receivers` is a list containing `R` lists, which represent the vector components of the `pr`'s (e.g. `[[p1x, p1y, p1z], [p2x, ...`).

I'm not sure where to begin translating this to something workable in `SciPy`. For one, here I "dynamically" generate symbols for the unknowns `t_1, t_2,.... t_T`, in addition to a number of other unknowns (`vx`, `vy`, `x`, etc). I'm not sure how one would translate this symbolic expression with a potentially large, dynamic number of symbolic unknowns.

If I could simply rewrite the expression as something compatible with the `SciPy` solvers, moving forward with solving it should be fairly trivial.

**How can this be approached?**

Comment: In the given SymPy code, it looks like the vectors `p_r`, `x0` and `v` have length 3.  Is that correct?

Comment: Can you summarize the number of scalar equations that you end up with, and the number of unknowns (expressed as functions of T and R)?  Are they the same?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes, that's right. `p_r`, `x0`, and `v` have length `3` (i.e. are `3D` vectors). The total number of equations (of the form given in the LaTeX above) will be `R x I`. The vectors `v = <vx,vy,vz>`, `x0 = <x,y,z>`, and the `ti`'s are unknown . `R` will be larger than or equal to `3`, and `T` will be larger than or equal to `5`.

Comment: *"The total number of equations ... will be `R x I`."*  Did you mean `R x T`?  So you have `R x T` equations, and `T + 6` unknowns.  With more equations than unknowns, you won't (in general) be able to solve the system exactly, so I assume you are looking for a [least-squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) solution.  Is that correct?

Comment: Can you show actual runnable code that demonstrates the issue with nsolve? Just put in some made up values for data etc. It wouldn't be hard to show how to convert this for scipy and in fact SymPy can do it for you with lambdify but I'm not going to spend my own time filling in the blanks in your code. Note that if nsolve struggles then it's possible that your equations are badly conditioned in which case scipy won't necessarily be able to help.